# Error message not converting html tags

Tags: 8, debugging

In entity browser I tried uploading a file which is not supported. So I got the valid error message.
But it does not convert the html tags which are being generated from token.
Following is the code from core **File** module.

```
function file_validate_extensions(FileInterface $file, $extensions) {
  $errors = [];  
  $regex = '/\.(' . preg_replace('/ +/', '|', preg_quote($extensions)) . ')$/i';
  if (!preg_match($regex, $file->getFilename())) {
    $errors[] = t('Only files with the following extensions are allowed: %files-allowed.', ['%files-allowed' => $extensions]);
  }
  return $errors;
}
```

This error message when searched in translations is shown as:

> Only files with the following extensions are allowed: %files-allowed.

which is perfectly fine.
But this is how it is being displayed on page:

[image: error message]

How to debug this?

Comment: Sounds like https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_browser/issues/2927464

Comment: @Andy Yes, it's the same issue. And there is no solution for it yet.